# Разобрать json на Java c json-simple-1.1.1

Tags: java, json, парсер

Получаю сложный ответ в JSON:

```
{"18610211":{"UF_UDA20":"1","EXT":{"UF_UDA20":"1","UF_SPEC_PRICE":"0","PRICE":"11 100<span class=\"price-kop\">,00<\/span>","UF_COUNT":"1","UF_SPEC_OFFER":"0","UF_PRICE":"11100.00","UF_NAL":"0",
```

как мне добраться до PRICE?

```
 JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    try {

        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("json.txt"));

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        System.out.println(jsonObject);

        String name = (String) jsonObject.get("PRICE");
        System.out.println(name);


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Мне кажется, должно получится что-то такого типа: ```String price=jsonObject.getJSONObject("18610211").getJSONObject("EXT").getString("PRICE");```

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
try {

    Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("json.txt"));

    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
    System.out.println(jsonObject);


    String name = (String) jsonObject.get("18610211").get("EXT").get("PRICE");
    System.out.println(name);


} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: а что делать если `18610211` всегда разные?

Comment: тогда надо менять json

Comment: как понять что там не `18610211`, a `18610212`?

Comment: может для этой цели лучше регулярка?

Comment: количество способов определить это не имеет границ.