# Почему я постоянно получаю null вместо значения строки в JSON?

Tags: java, json, парсер, gson

Я пробовал две библиотеки для работы с JSON: GSON и FastJson.

JSON (кусок):

```
{
...
"Layout1BottomContent": ["Selection'@string/Selection'", "Folder'@string/New'",  "*NewDir'@string/NewDir'", "*NewFile'@string/NewFile'", "Folder'Open'", "*OpenAssoc'@string/OpenAssoc'", "*OpenWith'@string/OpenWith'", "*OpenAs'@string/OpenAs'", "Delete'@string/Delete'", "Copy'@string/Copy'", "Compress'@string/Compress'", "Extract'@string/Extract'", "Folder'Menu'"],
"Layout1BottomAppearance": ["60", "Fit", "Center", "Rounded", "Icon", "Expandable"],
"Layout1Top": "NormBarPinned",
...
}
```

Пытался парсить через FastJson:

```
public class MainPageBasicLayout extends AppCompatActivity {

    int Layout1BottomLvl1Num = 0;
    String[] Layout1BottomLvl1Features = new String[9];
    String[] Layout1BottomLvl1Items = new String[9];

    //JSON Fields
    @JSONField
    String Layout1Bottom = null;
    @JSONField
    List<String> Layout1BottomContent;
    @JSONField
    List<String> Layout1BottomAppearance;
    @JSONField
    String ExitBehavior;
    @JSONField
    int Layout1BottomNum = 0;

    public MainPageBasicLayout() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);


        //Get JSON file content

        String JSON = null;
        try {
            JSON = new CfgMgr().GetJsonFileContent(this);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        MainPageBasicLayout Obj = com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON.parseObject(JSON, MainPageBasicLayout.class);

}
```

Потом пытался через GSON:

```
public class MainPageBasicLayout extends AppCompatActivity {

    int Layout1BottomLvl1Num = 0;
    String[] Layout1BottomLvl1Features = new String[9];
    String[] Layout1BottomLvl1Items = new String[9];

    //JSON Fields
    @Expose
    String Layout1Bottom = null;
    @Expose
    List<String> Layout1BottomContent;
    @Expose
    List<String> Layout1BottomAppearance;
    @Expose
    String ExitBehavior;
    @Expose
    int Layout1BottomNum = 0;

    public MainPageBasicLayout() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);


        //Get JSON file content

        String JSON = null;
        try {
            JSON = new CfgMgr().GetJsonFileContent(this);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

           GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = builder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
        MainPageBasicLayout Obj = gson.fromJson(JSON, MainPageBasicLayout.class);
}
```

---

А затем я пытаюсь выполнить `Integer.parseInt(Layout1BottomAppearance.get(0))`, но получаю:

```
NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference
```

P.S. Код GetJsonFileContent:

```
public String GetJsonFileContent(Context Context) throws IOException {

        File Cfg = new File("/data/data/mate.files/", "Cfg.json");

        String PreparedData = "";
        int CfgLength = CfgStr.getBytes().length;
        char[] Char;
        Char = new char[CfgLength];
        InputStreamReader InputRdr = new InputStreamReader(Context.openFileInput("Cfg.json"));
        InputRdr.read(Char, 0, CfgLength);

        int Counter = 0;
        //Convert char array to String
        for (Counter = 0; Counter != CfgLength; Counter++) {
            PreparedData = PreparedData + Char[Counter];
        }
        InputRdr.close();

        return PreparedData;
    }
```

Comment: Попробуй json-simple, парсер вот например [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/854556/204920) читай как надо это делать. Если возникнут ошибки то надо постить стэктрейс.

Comment: Если ответ решил ваш вопрос - отметьте его галочкой. См: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Объяснение ошибки

Я полагаю, что все из-за того, что Вы извлекаете данные из JSON'да и кладёте их в один объект, а потом пытаетесь получить их из другого.

**На примере:**

```
MainPageBasicLayout Obj = com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON.parseObject(JSON, MainPageBasicLayout.class);
```

Вы извлекаете данные из JSON и сохраняете их в `Obj`

После чего вы вызываете следующий код:

```
Integer.parseInt(Layout1BottomAppearance.get(0))
```

Здесь не указано, где именно он расположен, но насколько могу себе представить он расположен внутри `MainPageBasicLayout`, а если это так, то в двух вышеприведенных строках вы обращаетесь к разным объектам.

Отсюда и следует `NullPointerException`:
Вы сохранили данные в `Obj`, а потом пытаетесь получить их же в `this`.

Вы должны были обращаться:

```
Obj.Layout1BottomAppearance.get(0)
```

а вместо этого обратились

```
this.Layout1BottomAppearance.get(0)
```

(ссылка `this` используется неявно и здесь я ее подставил, чтобы вы понимали, что это разные объекты )

#### Рекомендации

Я бы предостерег Вас от попыток вручную создавать и манипулировать объектами Activity - оставьте это на откуп Android'у

Отсюда следует что не стоит пытаться из JSON'а создать Activity.

Если хотите что-то извлечь из JSON и применить к Activity:

1. Создайте отдельный класс настроек Activity, например ActivitySettings
2. Извлеките данные из JSON в объект данного типа.
3. Примените настройки используя полученный объект

#### Пример

Создаем класс описывающий модель хранимых в JSON данных

```
public class ActivitySettings {
    @Expose
    String Layout1Bottom = null;
    @Expose
    List<String> Layout1BottomContent;
    @Expose
    List<String> Layout1BottomAppearance;
    @Expose
    String ExitBehavior;
    @Expose
    int Layout1BottomNum = 0;
    // ...
}
```

Ну и потом извлекаем:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = builder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
ActivitySettings settings = gson.fromJson(JSON, ActivitySettings.class);
```

результат в дебаггере

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как видим в `settings` прекрасно хранятся значения из Json.

И потом вы можете их брать и использовать как вам нужно.

#### Замечание

Вы часто используете имена

- переменных (`Obj`),
- полей (`ExitBehavior`),
- методов (`GetJsonFileContent()`)

начинающихся с заглавной буквы

В Java так делать **нельзя**!

В Java есть конвенции, которые четко определяют, что названия классов всегда должны начинаться с заглавной, а переменных и методов с прописной.

Если боитесь за различие название полей в классе и JSON'е -  используйте аннотацию `@SerializedName` с указанием названия поля в JSON

```
public class ActivitySettings {
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("Layout1Bottom")
    String layout1Bottom = null;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("Layout1BottomContent")
    List<String> layout1BottomContent;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("Layout1BottomAppearance")
    List<String> layout1BottomAppearance;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("ExitBehavior")
    String exitBehavior;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("Layout1BottomNum")
    int layout1BottomNum = 0;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Странно, но ```Integer.parseInt(Obj.Layout1BottomAppearance.get(0))``` не изменило ситуацию.

Comment: @HumanNo1, приведите полностью код класса, в котором вы это используете.

Comment: @HumanNo1  я про то, где вы пытаетесь вызвать `Integer.parseInt(Obj.Layout1BottomAppearance.get(0))`

Comment: @HumanNo1 - сообщите когда приложите код

Comment: За ответ - спасибо большое! А дальше - это я про аннотации забыл. Опять моя невнимательность. Извините.